# For two given positive numbers a and b. Find a raised to b. Output your number modulus 10^9+7

Tags: java, arrays

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/abset-2/0/ , this is a gfg question where i am asked to output my number (a ^ b) modulus 10^9+7.

so here is my first code;

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    while(t--!=0){
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        
        int result = 1;
        
        for(int i = 0; i<b; i++){
            result = result*a;
            
        }
        System.out.println(result%1000000007);
    }
}
```

and it is not giving the correct output for 99^928. Then i changed the data type of result into long even that's giving a negative number. Then i had to change my code like this and it worked

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    while(t--!=0){
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        
        long result = 1;
        
        for(int i = 0; i<b; i++){
            result = (result*a);
            result = result%1000000007;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

here my question is when i put the result%1000000007 in the for loop how it worked, according to the problem was not i supposed to output the ****ultimate result** modulus 10^9+7**?

Answer (score 0):

`int` and `long` have maximum values. Depending on `a` and `b` `a^b` exceeds that maximum and overflows.

The modulo operation in the end would then act on the wrong overflow value and the result would be off.

The thing with modulo is that you can apply modulo during your computation basically whenever you want without changing the result. `(a + b) mod m` has the same value as `(a mod m + b mod m) mod m` and similarly `(a * b) mod m` is the same as `(a mod m * b mod m) mod m`, that is simply how the modulo operator works. Simply play around with a few small values of a b and m on paper to see that the rules work.

It is very typical for assignments involving HUGE values to be computable only if you add some `mod m` steps somewhere in the mix (as long as they make sense).

Answer (score 0):

99^928 is a [large number with 1852 digits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=99%5E928). The primitive data types int and long in Java don't have the storage capacity for such a number: the largest value you can store in an int is 2147483647 and the largest you can store in a long is 9223372036854775807. Operations that return larger values wrap around, returning a value that is correct modulo a power of 2, but completely unusable for most practical purposes.

If you printed out the intermediate values, you would see the result wrap around already at 99^10:

- 99^9 = 913517247483640899
- 99^10 = -1795512867667309079

This means if you wait to do the modulo operation until the last moment, you will be taking the modulo of an incorrect intermediate result. You must control how large the values get by using modulo already in the intermediate steps.

Note that Java does have classes for dealing with integers bigger than fits in a long: `java.math.BigInteger`. It even has a convenient and fast method for the "modular power" operation you are implementing:

```
BigInteger base = BigInteger.valueOf(1000000007);
BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(a).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(b), base);
```